# RSS feed scrape with separated page for the article

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping, rss, feed

I have a really simple question.
I am scraping data from rss feed.

Rss feed format:

```
<item>
<title></title>
<link></link>
<description></description>
<pubDate></pubDate>
<guid></guid>
<dc:date></dc:date>
</item>
```

And this is my code to display the last 7 posts.

```
<?php
$url = "**THE URL I AM SCRAPING DATA FROM**";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
$i = 0;
if (!empty($rss))
{
    $site = $rss
        ->channel->title;
    $sitelink = $rss
        ->channel->link;
    foreach ($rss
        ->channel->item as $item)
    {
        $title = $item->title;
        $link = $item->link;
        $description = $item->description;
        $item->description = strip_tags($item->description);
        $date = $item->pubDate;
        $pubDate = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($date));
        if ($i >= 7) break;
?>

<div class="post-item">
    <div class="post-item-wrap">
        <div class="post-image">
            <a href="<?php echo $link;?>">
                <img alt="" src="images/news/nra.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="post-item-description">
            <span class="post-meta-date"><?php echo $pubDate;?></span>
            <h2><a href="<?php echo $link ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $title;?>
            </a></h2>
            <p><?php echo implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $description), 0, 30)) . "..";?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo $link;?>" class="item-link">learn more <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

My question is, how do I make the *a href* tag target each post separately. I mean, display the article on my website, not redirecting to the main source. I don't have access to the database and can't grant either, I am just trying to scrape the data from rss feed and display each post separately.

`www.mywebsite.com/post<?php echo $link ?>`?

Here is a website that already did, what I am trying to achieve.

https://kik-info.com/novini/nap/

I accept any suggestions, not only php solutions.. may be also javascript and etc.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why don't you make a cron to scrap and store in your database then fetch from it?

Comment: I don't want to insert into a db. I am just making a grid post overview where I set the description to `(' ', $description), 0, 30))` and I want to make a single post where to display the full description.That's all.

Comment: Ok.. in link put guid from rss and reload the page on same screen with query param like `?post=1254` and in your loop check if post exists then show the post  else do whatever you are doing

Comment: @danish-khan-I could you send me the code, I understood your logic. And on the post.php page I need code to check if post-id equal to post and than display.